# Password Protected Files in Directory using .htaccess and .htpasswd, but files do not display

Tags: apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I created a password protected files using .htaccess and .htpasswd, but it doesnt show up when I goto the URL.

I have this in my htaccess:

```
#Protect multiple files
<FilesMatch "^(.*).csv$">
AuthName "Dialog prompt"                                                                                                                                                                                       
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /xxxxx/test                                                                                                                                              
#AuthUserFile ".htpasswd"                                                                                                                                                                                      
Require valid-user                                                                                                                                                                                             
</FilesMatch>
```

[image]

Comment: Emmm, that configuration file is invalid. You will see a syntax error in your http server's error log file. You need to remove those line numbers.

Comment: no those are just line numbers i copied from VIM. ignore that.